# Processing of queries using SparkSQL on difference databases

Tags: apache-spark, apache-spark-sql

I want to use Spark SQL (installed on Machine 1) with connectors for different data stores like HBase, Hive, Cassandra, and MySQL (installed on Machine 2 to perform simple analytics like Min/Max, averaging, etc.

My Question: Is the processing of these queries done on Machine 1 or Spark SQL acts as just an interface to perform different analytics but on the data store end (ie. Machine 2)?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Yes and no. It depends on your spark job.

Spark SQL is a separate implementation. It is datastore agnostic. When you implement a spark sql job , spark transforms it into something called DAG.
It is a similar technique to a database query plan, but running completely on the spark cluster.

In case of simple min / max, it might be translated into a direct underlying store query. But it might also be translated into something which is preselecting bunch of records, then doing an own data processing. This way it is also possible to join and aggregate data from different data sources.

You can analyze the spark sql plan with common [explain](https://spark.apache.org/docs/latest/sql-ref-syntax-qry-explain.html) statement or via spark [web ui](https://spark.apache.org/docs/3.0.0/web-ui.html).